# Delay in a 'for' loop in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, delay, timedelay

I have this code, and I want to make a delay in the `for` loop to measure one time and then make a delay and continue after that.

I tried:

```
timout / t 10/ nobreak
```

As it is shown in the code, but it didn't work.

```
: @echo off

set Looping_number=10 or anything else

FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%Looping_number%) DO call :doit %%A
goto :eof

:doit
set pad=00%1
set num=%pad:~-2%
@set var1=var1.exe
@set var2=C:\...\...\... .txt
@set output=C:\....\output\%num% 
Mkdir %output%
%var1%     %var2%     %Results%  
timeout / t 10 / nobreak
goto :eof
```

But it says you can not delay?

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have extra spaces in your command:

```
timeout / t 10 / nobreak
```

You need to say:

```
timeout /t 10 /nobreak
```

Comment: it is so ridiculous from my side
Thank you

Comment: Because timeout generate output, but yes, we could use timeout or the ping solution as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the `ping` method:

```
ping -n 10 localhost > nul
```